# Typescript ImplicitAnyIndexErrors

Tags: typescript

Recently I decide to make my TS project stricter, so I remove `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors: true` line, then I encountered this problem

```js
type WebLocksEnabledBrowser = "chrome" | "edge-chromium" | "edge";
class LeaderElection {
  private enableWebLock: boolean;
  private webLockMinBrowserList = {
        chrome: 69,
        "edge-chromium": 79,
        edge: 79,
    } satisfies Record<WebLocksEnabledBrowser, number>;
  constructor(browserInfo: { name: string, version: number }) {
    // First Approach, two errors
    if (this.webLockMinBrowserList[browserInfo.name]) {
      this.enableWebLock = this.webLockMinBrowserList[browserInfo.name] >= browserInfo.version
    } else {
      this.enableWebLock = false;
    }

    // Second Approach, no error, but still need a type cast
    if (browserInfo.name in this.webLockMinBrowserList) {
      this.enableWebLock = this.webLockMinBrowserList[browserInfo.name as WebLocksEnabledBrowser] >= browserInfo.version
    } else {
      this.enableWebLock = false;
    }
    
    // Third approach, passed all checks, but need a unnecessary predicate function
    if (predicate(browserInfo.name)) {
      this.enableWebLock = this.webLockMinBrowserList[browserInfo.name] >= browserInfo.version
    } else {
      this.enableWebLock = false;
    }
  }
}

function predicate(browserName: string): browserName is WebLocksEnabledBrowser {
  return ["chrome", "edge-chromium", "edge"].includes(browserName);
}
```

TS doesn't automatically narrow down `browserInfo.name` in first and second approach, I need to add a cumbersome predicate function as third approach did. Are there any missing pieces I don't know about TS so I can make it to narrow down `browserInfo.name` automatically. I also want to use as less `as` as possible.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAx1XN)

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you are giving a string as a parameter when your `webLockMinBrowserList` object waits for a key of type : `WebLocksEnabledBrowser`

Either you restrict your browserInfo obj with : `browserInfo: { name: WebLocksEnabledBrowser, version: number }` or you map your string to the type WebLocksEnabledBrowser with a switch or so... (basically implements your predicat).

Typescript cannot make for you the switch between a string and WebLocksEnabledBrowser ;)

PS: the third option (predicat) is by far the best one. (If you implement it correctly and not returning just true by default !)

Comment: I can't restrict browserInfo obj with `browserInfo: { name: WebLocksEnabledBrowser, version: number }` cauz user may indeed pass in other browser names which in result I will set `enableWebLock` to false. The third option feels unnecessary to me, cause using `in` or `this.webLockMinBrowserList[browserInfo.name]` is totally valid runtime check, I don't want to implement another proper predicate function. As all, I meant to seek for a simple solution which can pass TS checks without using any type cast.

Comment: If no other means is better, I tend to choose option 2 since it requires less type:)